# Enhanced Search for Android App

Tags: feature-request, search, android-app

I'd like to suggest an enhanced search functionality. Two things that come to my mind right now are:

1. I want to be able to save search requests like bookmarks. E.g., if I search for `[java] or [groovy]` and sort it by date, I want to remember this search and not type it freshly in each time I reopen the app.
2. A `[<mytags>]` placeholder or similar would be nice to always search the current list of favorite tags, being able to sort it by any criterion. Currently there is only one sorting option that shows unanswered questions in my tags in voting order. This is not too helpful for me if I want to do some easy helping on newest questions in my tags.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) and create your own query.

[Here's an example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/463100/find-questions-containing-a-single-tag) of one I wrote to find questions with a single tag only.

Comment: That is a nice tool I didn't know of. But I have three questions.  
1. where can these queries be used? Only from data.stackexchange.com, or are they then integrated into the SO website and android app? Because my suggestion was mainly for the Android App, hence the tag android-app.
2. The data there is quite old, newest java question is from 2016-04-03 04:04:16, almost a week ago.
3. How can I query for my favorite tags? I didn't find any table / column where those are stored.

Comment: **1.** Can only be used in the data explorer, didn't realise you wanted this as an app feature. **2.** It only returns questions with a ***single*** tag - if the latest java question(s) have more than just the [java] tag they will be ignored. That being said, the data is only updated weekly **3.** There is a whole table just for tags in the data explorer, plus the tags column appears on other tables

Comment: Well then, this is not useful for my use-case and feature request. But interesting nontheless. About **3.**, but how do I find out which tags are marked favourite by myself?

Comment: The data explorer is generic, it's not linked to your profile information in any way so you wouldn't be able to search for that kind of thing unfortunately.

Comment: Well, somewhere the info should be present, shouldn't it? I can also query my displayname, location, etc.

Comment: You can search profile information as a separate table, but there's no relation to things like favourite tags, is what I was trying to say.